# Input string was not in a correct format retriving value from label

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string labeldistance = lbldistance.Text;
string output = Regex.Match(labeldistance, @"\d+").Value;
double labeldistance1 = Convert.ToDouble(output);
double carMilege = 10;
double cost = 70;
lblResult.Text = ((labeldistance1/carMilege)*cost).ToString();
```

[retrieving value from label and label contains both string and integer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qftTp.png)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You're trying to convert a string into a double.  What about the string, does not easily fit when trying to make it a double?  Also, please [edit] your question so the error is present, and not just a screenshot.

Comment: Please refrain from linking to pictures of code or errors. Instead, paste the error directly into your post.

Comment: Check the value of output. There is something in there that cannot be converted.

Comment: The error means that the value being passed to `Convert.ToDouble` cannot be converted. What is the value of the string `output`?

Comment: When you say the label contains both `string` and `integer`, you mean that the `string` value of the `Text` property contains both non-numeric and numeric characters? If that's the case, then you'll have to parse out the numeric characters first, before passing it to `Convert.ToDouble`

Comment: label contains 48.1km

Comment: the label generates values in both string and integer . eg- 45.6km, 34.1km ..... and i want to convert 45.6 km into 45.6 and then use the value in lblresult.txt

Answer (score 0):

You Need to first make your string an int

```
   string labeldistance = lbldistance.Text;
   labeldistance.ToInt32();
   string output = Regex.Match(labeldistance, @"\d+").Value;
   double labeldistance1 = Convert.ToDouble(output);
```

EDIT: If you need it to a float just do the same thing, just

```
  labeldistance.ToFloat();
```

Comment: I just saw your comment, You cannot have 'km' in the label. its not a number, therefor cannot be converted to a float/int @Ghanshyam Kumar

Comment: thanks for taking my question. the label generates values in both string and integer and eg- 45.6km, 34.1km ..... and i want to convert 45.6 km into 45.6 and then use the value in lblresult.txt

Comment: Okay so then what you have missing a part that will capture the decimal. you need `labeldistance, @"\d+(.\d+)?"`. Then you output it.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding the error:**

> Input string was not in a correct format retriving value from label

This error appears when the input string to `Convert.ToDouble()` contains no numbers so in your program, `output` definitely does not have any numbers.

```
Convert.ToDouble(""); // throws System.FormatException: Input string was 
                      // not in a correct format.

Convert.ToDouble("48.1") // works fine
```

So you should debug, set a breakpoint and check if `lbldistance.Text` really contains '48.1km', and then if `output` contains 48.

**Extracting the number using regex:**

As per your example, it looks like you want to extract 48.1 using the double variable. For that you might want to tweak you regex like this:

```
\d+(.\d+)?
```

This will capture numbers containing decimals too. Here's a working demo using this regex and parts of your code:

```
string labeldistance = "48.1km";
string output = Regex.Match(labeldistance, @"\d+(.\d+)?").Value;
double labeldistance1 = Convert.ToDouble(output);
Console.WriteLine(labeldistance1);
// Outputs 48.1
```

[Dotnet Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ql0sGy)

So if you can ensure `lbldistance.Text` really contains 48.1km then using the above regex you should be able to get your desired output.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Always sanitize input you get from the user:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace StackOverflow_Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string input = "Label: +1,234.56";
            string sanitized = Regex.Match(input, @"[0-9\.\+\-\,]+").Value; // filters out everything except digits (0-9), decimal points (.), signs (+ or -), and commas (,)
            double distance = Convert.ToDouble(sanitized);

            Console.WriteLine($"Input => \t\t{input}");             // Label: +1,234.56
            Console.WriteLine($"Standardized => \t{sanitized}");    // +1,234.56
            Console.WriteLine($"Distance => \t\t{distance}");       // 1234.56
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```